# How do you format code in visual studio 2012 for box selection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, code-formatting

I want to know if there is a way in Visual Studio (preferably 2012) to format code in such a way that it becomes very easy to apply [Box Selection and Multi-line-editing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/26/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing-with-vs-2010.aspx) to your code.

For example:

A shortkey that transforms this lump of code:

```
public class Example
{
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public short Order { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
}
```

Into something like this:

```
public class Example {
    public bool     IsDefault       { get; set; }
    public string   Description     { get; set; }
    public string   Link            { get; set; }
    public short    Order           { get; set; }
    public byte     Status          { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use [Code Alignment extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) for Visual Studio 2012.

I haven't try it, but it seems to do what you want : [Align by space feature](https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment/wiki/Align-by-space)